# Eye Strain and Nausea when running 18.04.1 on Intel i915 graphics

Tags: 18.04, display, desktop-environments, accessibility

When I launch Ubuntu 18.04.1 on my [Acer Aspire x3950](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/2187?b=1) desktop PC with Intel i915 graphics, I experience heavy eyes within 5-10 minutes, and after a few hours develop severe dizziness and sometimes headaches.

When I boot with Windows 7, it causes no strain at all, and I can use it for prolonged periods without issue.

I am part of a small but growing community at LED Strain (https://ledstrain.org) who experience these issues on most modern devices, games consoles, smartphones, even Smart TV apps cause problems. We believe there has been a change of rendering introduced (temporal dithering?) which may be the cause.

Does the Ubuntu desktop use any form of dithering, and is there a way to disable this as these extra artifacts on modern Operating systems are causing severe issues for a minority of users.

** 
PC Make / Model - Acer Aspire AX3950
Graphics - Intel GMA HD Graphics
Monitor - [Dell U2419H](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-ultrasharp-24-monitor-u2419h/apd/210-arcf/monitors-monitor-accessories) (via HDMI) its best res is 1920X1080 @ 60Hz

Output of `sudo lshw -C display`:

```
*-display                    
       description: VGA compatible controller   
       product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller   
       vendor: Intel Corporation   
       physical id: 2   
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0   
       version: 12    
       width: 64 bits   
       clock: 33MHz   
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom   
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0   
       resources: irq:26 memory:fb800000-fbbfffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:dc00(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux paul-Aspire-X3950 5.0.0-36-generic #39~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 11:09:50 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 12)

Comment: • Why have you used the `14.04` tag? • Have you tried Windows 10? Do you have a problem there as well?

Comment: Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 can't be really considered as "modern OS" now, because Windows 7 would be **EoL** in few months and 14.04 LTS is already **EoL**, only ESM version is updated, but is still off-topic here

Comment: I have the same problems in Windows 10 as well as the latest Ubuntu LTS.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issues re: link above, but there isn't a solution mentioned. I have used f.lux, use dark themes, change fonts and lower resolution, none of which make a difference. It is as if the Windows 10 desktop/Ubuntu desktop is rendered differently to Windows 7.

Comment: Please run `sudo lspci | grep -i vga` then click [edit] and add its result to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu (and Debian based Linux in general) give you much more diverse options than Windows; you can change your display environment from GNOME, change your window manager, and use either hardware manufacturer's drivers or open source nouveau drivers if you have NVIDIA graphics.

Bug [1776642](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1776642) discusses dithering with Intel HD 530 Graphics driver integrated into the Linux kernel with earlier versions of the kernel than you have.  You are using a Intel graphics driver. Therefore, I believe dithering is used on your graphics display as well, and suggest you add an update to that bug report that dithering is causing a problem with the 5.0 kernel.  (Also, bug [1819023](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1819023) discusses NVIDIA driver dithering.)

The bug report for your video driver mentioned [changing](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/diy-it-guy/diy-replace-ubuntu-unity-with-a-different-desktop/) from the GNOME desktop which is standard with Ubuntu 18 and up [to the KDE desktop](https://itsfoss.com/install-kde-on-ubuntu/) (it's standard with Kubuntu and easily added from the repositories you have with Ubuntu).

Therefore, I suggest you try the KDE desktop.

Also recommended has been adjusting the [gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction#Microsoft_Windows,_Mac,_sRGB_and_TV/video_standard_gammas) ([more](http://xahlee.info/img/what_is_gamma_correction.html)) with `sudo xgamma -gamma 0.7` which requires experimenting with the value (shown above as 0.7) to find the gamma which minimizes your eye strain the best.